# how to create a new observable subscription based on existing observable in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I need to do something as the following line in my project(from 
https://github.com/devyumao/angular2-busy)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.busy = this.http.get('...').subscribe();
}
```

In my project, I am making request based on route change as the following:

```
ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.activatedRoute
        .params
        .map(params => params['queryString'])
        .flatMap(id => this.http.(''))
        .subscribe(result => this.data = result);   
}
```

It seems I need to create a new subscription every time there is a change in route. I am not sure how to do it.

I am looking for rxjs solution only (without using Promise).

Thanks!

derek

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I need to create a new subscription every time there is a change in route". Your code creates a single subscription.

Comment: since `this.busy` is a subscription, and when the route changes, a new observable is created in the `.flatMap(id => this.http.(''))` and returned. The crux of the question is that how do I subscribe this.http.('') observable at the same time the original code still works.

Comment: I want to achieve something like `... .flatMap(id => this.busy = this.http.('').subscribe(...)) ...`. but it don't compile. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can subscribe to the ajaxCallObservable in the chain. :)

```js
ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.activatedRoute
        .params
        .map(params => params['queryString'])
        .map(id => this.http.(''))
        .do(ajaxCallObservable => { this.busy = ajaxCallObservable.subscribe() })
        .flatMap(ajaxCallObservable => ajaxCallObservable)
        .subscribe(result => this.data = result);   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would globally (in your main component for example) register on route changes this way and trigger your request in the associated callback:

```
this.router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
  // or NavigationEnd
  .subscribe(event => {
    this.http.post('').subscribe();
  });
```

This way you subscribe once on changes.

If you want to have access to route params, you need to inject the ActivateRoute instance as well and subscribe on its `params` attribute.

For this, I would leverage the `combineLatest` method of the `Observable` class, like described below:

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    Observable.combineLatest(
      this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart),
      this.route.params
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      const event = data[0];
      const params = data[1];
      (...)
    });
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
```

Comment: thanks. can you explain how you inject the ActivateRoute instance and subscribe on its `params` attribute at same time?

Comment: Tried the updated answer and it didn't work. The reason was the busy directive was waiting for the onComplete() which never happened.